# Can you automatically associate Javascript to a DOM element based on its CSS class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So right now I have an input validation method structured something like this:

```
function validate(element, regex);
```

'element' is the input DOM element and 'regex' is the regular expression that the method checks the user's input against. If the input doesn't matchup with regex, the input element outline changes to red. If the user input is valid, then the outline changes back to black.

Is there a way to associate this function with a CSS class so that every element with that class will automatically call that function?

```
<input type="text" id="text_field" class="yearvalidate"/>
```

So class "yearvalidate" would send a regular expression to validate() that limits the input to 4 digits. And this would be done automatically instead of explicitly writing Javascript to call validate for the textfield.

Is there a way to do this or do I have to make an explicit call in Javascript?

Comment: That's how most jquery validation plugins work. You give an element a class like 'required', or 'email', and on form submit (or onblur), the validation triggers.  take a look at this plugin: http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With jQuery:

```
$('input').each(function(i,e) {
  var regex = getRegex($(e).attr('class'));
  if (regex) validate(e, regex);
});
```

You'll have to create another function `getRegex()` for turning 'yearvalidate' into `/\d{4}/` though.

```
function getRegex(classname) {
   switch(classname) {
      case 'numbervalidate':
        return /\d+/;
        break;
      case 'yearvalidate':
        return /\d{4}/;
        break;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like -

```
$('.yearvalidate').change(function() {
  //check value using your regex
});
```

That will hook up a function that fires every time an element with the class 'yearvalidate' loses focus.

Answer (score 0):

You need some sort of framework to do the wiring for you.  My suggestion would be to use  jQuery to bind changes for any element with class "yearvalidate" to your validate function.

```
$(function() {
    $('.yearvalidate').change(validate);
});
```